# Shell Programming Regex error

Tags: powershell

I have a text file and I want to display a content from the file after searching for a word pattern.

My text file has following

```
Hello 2013, a7

Hello 2013, z8
errorprocessing adafda adasd adads adasdad adadsasd asdadsdasd adasdasdasda dadsadasda

Hello 2013, e1
```

My display should be

```
user: z8 
error: errorprocessing adafda adasd adads adasdad adadsasd asdadsdasd adasdasdasda dadsadasda
```

I could search errorproceesing pattern and display the content but I am unable to display xyz008 as this is a dynamic word and it may differ from one text file to another.

I need to search for

```
Hello [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9]
```

But I am not able get the desired output

I want to implement in Powershell I have `Select-String -Pattern [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9] -AllMatches -SimpleMatch –`

Comment: What kind of language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to implement in Powershell I have Select-String -Pattern [A-Z][0-9] -AllMatches -SimpleMatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (substitute your input filename for `file`):

```
do { # Dummy loop so we can exit the pipeline prematurely with `break`.
  get-content file | % {
    if ($_ -match '^Hello (\d{4}), ([a-z0-9]+)$') { # username found
      # Save it.
      $userName = $matches[2]
    } elseif ($_ -match '^errorprocessing ') { # error line found
      # Output desired result.
      "user: $userName`r`nerror: $_"
      # Exit pipeline (via dummy loop).
      break
    }
  }
} while ($false)
```

Note: The assumption is that you want to display only *one* username, namely *the most recent one preceding the error line*.

- The loop is necessary, because `Select-String` will not match *across* lines.
- A username is saved in the same variable whenever it is encountered, effectively only storing the *most recent* one.
- Once the error line is found, the most recent user name and the error line are output, as desired, and the pipeline is exited (in order to exit the pipeline with `break` before processing ALL lines, it had to be wrapped in a (dummy) *loop*).

Comment: can you help me for searching  2013, xyz008

Comment: @user3088731: Be more specific - what are the rules for what you need to find? There is no `2013` in your sample data. Please update your _question_ with clarifications - do NOT respond in a comment.

Comment: I have updated it sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: @user3088731: See my update; the regular expressions have been changed to match your _current_ sample data. Please don't keep changing the requirements: this solution should work in principle, even if tweaks to the regular expressions should be necessary - which you should be able to do by yourself. Also, after your edit your question now has partially outdated information - please fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply one small doubt if you dont mind If I have to save 2014 and z8 then what should I implement in $matches

Comment: @user3088731: I've updated my answer again so that `$matches[1]` will capture the year (any 4-digit sequence), and now `$matches[2]` the username - as you can see the subscripts of `$matches` correspond to the order of the capture groups (subexpressions enclosed in parentheses), starting with 1. Please use `help about_Comparison_Operators` in a PowerShell console and search for `-match` and `$Matches` to learn more.